# Output File is not getting saved on server to the given path

Tags: c#, asp.net, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I am creating an audio file from the inputted text and saving it into the "Sound" folder in my project directory using "**System.Speech dll**" / **SpeechSynthesizer**.
It works fine locally but after uploading on the server no file has been saved on the given path.
My code looks like as follows :

```
string hfdMVoice = Hiddenfield10.Value; // This is the inputted text
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Sound/") + HiddenFiledMaleVoice + ".mp3"; //this is the path where i have 
                                                                          // to save my output file.

Thread th = new Thread(() =>
            {
                speech = new SpeechSynthesizer();
                speech.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male, VoiceAge.Adult);
                speech.Volume = 100;
                speech.Rate = 0;
                if (hfdMVoice.EndsWith(".mp3"))
                {
                    hfdMVoice = hfdMVoice.Remove
                                           (hfdMVoice.Length - 4, 4);
                }
                speech.SetOutputToWaveFile(path); // This method saves the file on the given path.
                speech.SpeakAsync(hfdMVoice);
                string txt_ddd = hfdMVoice;
            });

            th.IsBackground = true;
            th.Start();
```

It works fine locally but doesn't work on server .

Answer (score 2):

You should check whether you have necessary write permissions on the output folder. If it is working on dev server but not working on production server then mostly it is because of access permissions not being granted.